# Why is my Chapter heading so strange?

Tags: sectioning

What could possibly cause this problem?
Normal is:
[image]

Mine is:[image]

The white space after "introduction" is also longer for mine.

What could possibly cause this problem?
I load

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

also;
I load

```
\usepackage{float}
```

Can anyone suggest me what could possibly go wrong? Thank you.

Minimal example code of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 
\newcommand*{\isotri}[1]{%
  \scalebox{1.118034}[1]{$#1$}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\pagestyle{plain} 
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\hypersetup{colorlinks   = true}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=black}
\hypersetup{citecolor=black}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction.
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{document}
```

Update of situation: I get the normal font by commenting out `%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. But I still cannot solve the problem of the longer white space after "introduction". Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: As long as you do not post a full minimal example, showing the problem, that we can copy and test on our own systems, it is very hard to help.

Comment: Are you using the package `setspace` and `\onehalfspacing`?

Comment: actually the whole document seems to have strange fonts too. I wonder if `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` cause this problem. Yes i will provide the code of minimal example soon, but it seems that the font of the whole document also is affected so i need to tidy things up.

Comment: @ egreg Yes i used `setspace` but did not use `\onehalfspacing`.

Comment: No, neither fontenc not inputenc is responsable.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your code (TeX Live 2015). Do you really need the entire preamble to show the problem? If you remove all the packages and other stuff that doesn't influence the problem, it will make it easier to troubleshoot.  (Unrelated notes: Don't load packages twice. `mathtools` loads `amsmath`. You have a `\bibliographystyle` which I guess shouldn't be there as you're using `biblatex`.)

Comment: did you try `\documentclass[10pt, oneside]{book}`

Comment: Update: I get the normal font by commenting out `%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. But I still cannot solve the problem of the longer white space after "introduction". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably no one has seen your comment, you are the only one who is notified of comments by default. Anyways, if you edit your example code by removing all the packages etc. from the preamble that *doesn't* influence the problem, and also state in the question itself that removing `fontenc` fixes the problem, the question will become much clearer. Editing the question will also push it to the front page.

Comment: That example is not at all minimal! Does uncommenting *any* of those lines really eliminate the problem? If so, just remove one of the lines which reloads a package a second time. If not, remove the lines which aren't needed to produce the problem. Note that vertical spacing is *designed* to stretch a bit. Its stretchiness enables TeX to improve the points at which pages are broken.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, either with the non-minimal MWE nor with a very reduced example. The question is unclear!